# API V2.0 Public Beta Begins

Tags: discussion, api-v2

[As has been announced](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-public-beta/), we're starting the public beta and spinning up a contest (as we did with V1.0).

As such, some of the guidelines for the private beta no longer apply.

The [api-v2-beta](/questions/tagged/api-v2-beta) tag no longer exists, questions pertaining to V2 should merely be tagged [api-v2](/questions/tagged/api-v2).  I've deleted most of the private-beta specific posts, as [I said I would](https://stackapps.com/questions/2701/api-v2-private-beta-begins).

You can now list V2.0-only applications just like any other, likewise for libraries.

We're also switching gears a bit, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) posts are much less likely to be implemented now as we're striving for stability now.  There are still a couple of things in the "maybe" pipeline, but the bar has been raised on new suggestions.

Some of things that we know still need polish/completion:

- the app authorization dialog

  - it's gotten better, but still a bit rough UI wise
  - still not HTTPS pure, we're working on getting all app icons onto our CDN to alleviate this
- request stats not implemented

  - authorization stats were more important
  - this should be done this week or early next week
  - delay caused by minor holdups in getting the data into a quick to query form
- type documentation

  - there have been improvements, but type docs aren't nearly as well polished as method ones
  - compare [/questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) and the [question type](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
  - we're still very much open to suggestions for improving the docs

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place, but: If the suggested edits queue is now completely public via the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits), what's the point of not making it available via the site until 5k rep? Low-rep users have no business there, but you can review starting at 2k.

Comment: @lunboks - user's can't act on suggested edits until they hit higher rep, so showing them on the sites would be confusing.  The same objections don't apply to the API, as there's no-one to confuse.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Is there a list of which features are new in 2.0? I'm thinking of entering the app contest and want to make sure I don't write an app that ends up using only older calls.

Comment: @Anna - the most obvious new thing is [authentication](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), but the most important thing is hitting the [/2.0/ endpoint](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and not the [/1.x/ ones](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage).  Most of the workhorse methods are *very* similar, by design.

Comment: Contest... **yaaaaay!**

Comment: I assume the 1.1 registration page will stick around at least until the public beta is over; can that page be updated to be explicit about it being for 1.1 keys like the 2.0 one is? There's been a few cases recently where people have signed up for a 1.1 key inadvertently then been confused when it doesn't work against the 2.0 API, possibly in part because the 1.1 registration page is the one linked from [`/about`](http://stackapps.com/about)